# Can record from TargetDataLine only first time

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have a Runnable that gets a line to the Mic, reads from it and stores it in an OutputStream.
When I start the 1st instance of this thread it works.
After 1st thread completes (exists run() method) i start another instance of the thread but this time i get:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame,  not supported.
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
```

My thread looks like this:

```
public void run() {
     float sampleRate = 44100.00F;
        //8000,11025,16000,22050,44100
        int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
        //8,16
        int channels = 2;
        //1,2
        boolean signed = true;
        //true,false
        boolean bigEndian = false;
        //true,false
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate,
           sampleSizeInBits,
           channels,
           signed,
           bigEndian);

    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format); // format is an AudioFormat object

    // Obtain and open the line.
    try {
        targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        targetLine.open(format); //exception is throw here
        targetLine.start();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CountingOutputStream countingOutStream = new CountingOutputStream(out);
        int numBytesRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[targetLine.getBufferSize() / 5];

        File binFile = new File("C:\\audio\\random4.txt");
        FileOutputStream fr = new FileOutputStream(binFile);


        while ( (countingOutStream.getCount()/1024) < targetSizeKB) {
           numBytesRead =  targetLine.read(data, 0, data.length);
           countingOutStream.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
        }    




        fr.write(newByte,0,ii);
        countingOutStream.close();
        fr.close();

       targetLine.flush();
        targetLine.stop();
        targetLine = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `flush` and `stop` on `targetLine`, but you don't call `close` - I suspect you need to do that in order to release it properly. (It's not clear why `targetLine` is an instance variable, by the way - does it need to be?)

You should also be doing all the clean-up in `finally` blocks, so that the streams get closed even if an exception is thrown.